# How to create an auto installing USB driver for Windows

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, autorun

On your computer, when you connect a USB device such as a camera, you get a pop up saying "Installing drivers please wait" or something along those lines. It runs the driver EXE file without requiring any permission from the user and without having the AutoPlay feature enabled.

I have a USB Key with 4gb of storage and I would like to let the same process happen to it upon inserting it, but using an EXE file I created instead of a real driver. (The file I created isn't in anyway harmful to the PC)

How I would want it to happen:

1. USB key is inserted to PCs USB port
2. Windows finds a required driver on the USB key
3. Windows runs the .exe
4. The fake driver carrys out it's duties on the PC

The .exe I have created is called "start.exe". It is a exe which was converted from a batch file which contained commands that do the following:

1. Deactivates muted volume
2. Sets volume level to highest value possible
3. Opens Google Chrome and Internet explorer on various different videos from                           the internet

The reason I want to do this is because the PC the USB is inserted into may not have Autorun enabled and therefore it won't run the autorun.inf I have placed in the USBs storage which also runs my "start.exe"

Any help is appreciated:)

Comment: Not strictly answering your question (writing a custom driver) but related: [Using AutoRun with a USB Flash Drive (USB stick)](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/autorun-usb-flash-drive.htm)

Comment: MSDN has a whole chapter on [USB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538930.aspx) and writing USB drivers. But I don't think you can replace a USB device's default driver with a custom driver without resorting to some low level hardware hacks.

Comment: Even if you modified the USB key to look like a custom device, you'd have to get Microsoft to distribute your executable as part of Windows and/or via Windows Update.  That's why the drivers you're talking about get installed silently, because Microsoft have authorized them to do so.